# ANativeWindow_lock and AndroidBitmap_lockPixels

Tags: android, performance, android-ndk

Into the ndk sample folder there is 2 sample (bitmap-plasma) and (native-plasma).
The first one write into a bitmap and then blit the bitmap on a surfaceview using AndroidBitmap_lockPixels.
The second is a full C application that write directly to the screen using ANativeWindow_lock.

What I'd like to do is to draw directly on a surfaceview.
Is it possible to do that with the ndk ?

Comment: You mean, is there a way to lockPixels on a SurfaceView's surface? I would like to know the same thing. There is very little documentation about ANativeWindow (I haven't seen any docs on the internet and minimal documentation in header file comments); for starters, I would really like to know the relationship between ANativeWindow and Activities/Views, and whether it is possible to mix ANativeWindow with a traditional Java Activity.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you guys still need help about this. There's another sample in NDK package, called `native-media`. There you can find an example of video playback onto a `Surface` object (which is passed in, as reference, to native source code).

They also provide an example of putting the video out using Java APIs instead, on the very same application.